# Solution for following sonar Issue?

Tags: java, sonarqube

following line of code in my code segment detected as an Issue by sonar.

code segment:

```
final int Pending=1;
```

sonar Issue:

> ```
>              Name 'Pending' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'.
> ```

why sonar detect this as an issue?

Comment: _naming convention_ for variables: they start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: yes. It is true about the variables. But here i define a constant. constant can have a name starting from Block letters.is that correct?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, Sonar gives an explicit message for the violation: the variable "Pending" does not match the given regexp pattern "^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$". This pattern means: any string that begins with a lowercase letter, followed by any letters or digits. So your variable should be called "pending", not "Pending".

What's more, as Juvanis said, this is the standard naming convention for variables in Java.